# Problem in Naming the Audio file in Facebook Post in Android

Tags: android, facebook, audio, post

Friends, I posted the Audio link to Facebook Friends wall without Dialog.
I'm able to play the Posted Audio link within Facebook, but i am unable to give title , name for it. Refer the Picture - I want to Post like [image: What i expect]..

[image: What i am getting]

Following is my code :

```
try{
String userID="1000021233268431111";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "name of link");
params.putString("title", "title of link");
params.putString("descrption", "descrption of link");
params.putString("caption", "Get utellit to send messages like this!");
params.putString("link", "http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3");
params.putString("type", "mp3");
params.putString("source", "http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3");
String  response = facebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", params, "POST");       
Log.v("response", response);
 }  catch(Exception e){
}
```

If i try to use the JSON Array to add attachment,nothing is added in the Parameter and i am getting Empty post like this:
[image]

Using JSON ARRAY mu code is :

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
    media.put("type", "mp3");
    media.put("src", "http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3");
    media.put("title", "Listen to your message");
    media.put("artist", "By: utellit for Android");
    media.put("album", "Utellit");
    attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    attachment.put("message", "Messages");
    attachment.put("name", "Get utellit to send messages like this!");
    attachment.put("href", "http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
String  response =facebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed",parameters, "POST");
Log.v("response", response);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i got it.. Here is my solution :

```
try{
String link="LINK that should goes if yoy click Get utellit to send messages like this";
String amazon_link=".mp3 link that should play inside Facebook";
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
    media.put("type", "mp3");
    media.put("src", amazon_link);
    media.put("title", "Listen to your message");
    media.put("artist", "By: utellit for Android");
    media.put("album", "Utellit");
    attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));
} catch (JSONException e1) {}

try {
    attachment.put("message", "Messages");
    attachment.put("name", "Get utellit to send messages like this!");
    attachment.put("href", link);
} catch (JSONException e) {}
parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
parameters.putString("target_id", "xxxx");  // target Id to post
parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
String  response = facebook.request(parameters);       
}
```

catch(Exception e){}

In `facebook.request`  method we should send only **parameters** and the **Method of post should added in Attachments**

Finally my Post in Facebook looks likes this :

[image]

Comment: Hi Venky, would this work with latest Facebook SDK? Please see my questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032973/posting-an-audio-mp3-file-through-feed-dialog-using-facebook-android-sdk

A bit of your kind help is required.