# Share photo with full size on facebook useing GRAPH API Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to post look like below image but with full size image.

[image]

I allreay use graph api to share photo on facebook which is something like below.
[image]

i want some hyperlink like above image and big photo.

pls.....guide me for this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Take a look for reference , not real answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581084/problem-in-naming-the-audio-file-in-facebook-post-in-android)

Comment: Seems we can't post full size image

Comment: That image is from URL Link or SDCard?

Comment: from url......................

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer No you can't show full sized image**.We will get only default size fixed by Facebook Graph API

Totally there are three types of Media attachments ,

1)  image

2)  flash

3)  mp3

**For image Media type :** You can't set user defined height and width , no such key/value pair for setting height and width.

**For Flash Media type :**  You can set Height and width , below are the key/value pair available for Flash type :

```
"width": "80", 
"height": "60",
"expanded_width": "160", 
"expanded_height": "120"
```

**For mp3** no need to discuss.

[Media attachments for Facebook post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/)

Comment: can we add more then one link like first image in my question??? if yes then how?

Comment: I am not sure about that , seems you need to work on HTML for adding multiple link

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows a pulished _Open Graph action_. See docs for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/