# Posting an audio MP3 file through Feed Dialog using Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android app and I have implemented sharing through Facebook SDK for Android, I am using [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/)

Everything working as written, however, as the content is Audio, I now also want to share MP3 files, just like SoundCloud does. Feed Dialog accepts a "source" parameter, which seems to accept a SWF or MP3 source URL. [Feed Dialog feature documentation is here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

However, when I embed Source parameter, it do exactly as it says on tin "If both source and picture are specified, only source is used." However, it don't live up to first promise which is: "The URL of a media file (either SWF or MP3) attached to this post."

My code is below:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("app_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    params.putString("name", "Name of Audio File");
    params.putString("caption", "Listen to Audios");
    params.putString("description", "Listen Listen Listen");
    params.putString("link", "applink on store");
    params.putString("picture", "picturehostedsomewhere.png");
    params.putString("source", "http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Shared on Facebook",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

What I see when I share the story is a story without any picture, it's just plain text with link, name, caption and description, no source, no picture, I assume either facebooksdk is having a problem in fetching the source or I am missing something here.
I am just wondering where I am heading wrong? Any help please?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this (_or could be this_): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/music.listens Never tried it personally, but I suppose this is what is used going by this post here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/19/developer-spotlight--soundcloud/

Comment: I guess to do this type of thing you need to be whitelisted with Facebook and Facebook would want to vet your content and have a revenue sharing partnership, in open graph music it says "Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at this time." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/ I guess I can safely assume that SoundCloud, Spotify and others in same league are Facebook Music Partners.

Comment: Correct. And in fact, they were part of the [Facebook F8 event](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2012/01/19/soundcloud-facebook-integration/) in September, 2011. I haven't had time to see if I can quickly patch their code in my app, but I think you can register for [Soundcloud's developer](http://developers.soundcloud.com/) access and then upload your audio files using their API using their [Android Sharing Kit](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/introducing-the-android-sharing-kit). Perhaps I could run a few test and see how it works out. But that will have to wait till tomorrow morning. :-(