# Post an mp3 to a users feed via the Feed Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ one can post mp3s to a users feed by constructing a URL like:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?+app_id=<APP-ID>+&display=popup&caption=<CAPTION>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT>&picture=<PICTURE>&source=<MP3-FILE>&description=<DESCRIPTION>`

This produces a share dialog, but when the source parameter is added, the file is not embedded on the page (nor is any link to the file given).

I had expected to be able to embed the mp3 like the documentation says. I seem to remember that facebook had it's own player to play embedded mp3 files from the feed - this is not showing up.

Has this functionality been disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the API still allows you to attach audio data but Facebook's audio player was removed in 2011 -

To play music inline now, you need to specify a flash player which loads the desired audio as an attached 'video' ( via the same 'source' parameter of the feed dialog )

You could also use a third party like Soundcloud who have a flash player for the content uploaded there

Comment: I just tried to add a flash .swf as source, it didn't show up either. This post has the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032973/posting-an-audio-mp3-file-through-feed-dialog-using-facebook-android-sdk - the conclusion there *seems* to be that you need to be a whitelisted partner in order to do this, even if this isn't ever spelled out in their docs.

Comment: The requirement to have your domain whitelisted in order to display inline video content was removed in 2011, possibly 2012 - it should work provided there isn't something like a HTTP/HTTPS mismatch between the user on Facebook and the video you're trying to embed

Comment: That was it, I had a HTTP/HTTPS mismatch, thanks a bunch. Would you mind getting a job at Facebook doing their documentation? I think the MP3 embedding feature could be removed from the docs when it's been disabled for 2 years.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you actually worked there:)